# Why image view located on top of recycler view is not displaying?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-imageview

I am trying to add an image view as a banner on top of recycler view. so in some condition I can hide (View.GONE) or to show that banner image view (View.VISIBLE). but the problem is, the banner image view will never show when I run the app, even though I have set `android:visibility="visible"` on the image view xml.

as you can see, I have image view with red background, but that red background image view will not displaying

how to solve this ?

the layout in my fragment is like this

[image]

and here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                                   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                   tools:context=".Fragments.Search.SearchKeywordResultFragment"
                                                   android:id="@+id/constraintLayout_search_keyword_fragment">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_general_event"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView_keyword_search_result"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_banner_search_keyword"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="#E91E63"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView_keyword_search_result"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars[3]" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Try adding `app:elevation="0dp"` to your `RecyclerView`

Comment: add this line to java file imageView.bringToFront();

Comment: try adding your java code for image .

Comment: you can use Layout inspector tool to debug and see your views hierarchy of your app: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector
you can find it in tools/Layout inspector, run it when you are running your app.

Comment: can you please provide me the layout of item of the recyclerview using constraintlayout ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because on your imageView have code line  `tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars[3]"` 
Tools function it will only show on android layout editor.
try change into real Image from bitmap or from drawable at `app:srcCompat="@drawable/{your_drawable_or_mipmap_data_file}"`

Comment: It't right, fake data at all of view in android studio with tools, ex: fake data at TextView: tools:text="Your Text"

Answer (score 0):

Just change your Recycler's TopToTop constrains to the id of the Image view and change it to TopToBottom.
For doing so you also need to declare the imageview first so you'll be able to address its Id.
Also give the banner width:match_parent

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_banner_search_keyword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="#E91E63"
        android:visibility="visible"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView_keyword_search_result"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars[3]" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_general_event"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_keyword_search_result"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="imageView_banner_search_keyword" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used same like this you can try it , it is working

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:shimmer="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/darkgrey"
tools:context=".ui.ProductList.ProductListFragment">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding_10"
        android:text=" Select an item closest to your desired search"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/product_list_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/list_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="bottom|center"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

On the place of viewpager you can use Imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` or `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` on your ImageView

Answer (score 0):

layout fixed. 
there was problem with your bottom approach of recycle view.
you are using **tools** for displaying image it will not show image on device or emulator for that you have to set Image using java/Kotlin code.

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img1)
imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.img1));
```

or if you are getting image form server then try using **Glide**  or anyother image loader Library.

```
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_general_event"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView_keyword_search_result"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView_banner_search_keyword"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_banner_search_keyword"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="#E91E63"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars[3]" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```